# Image keeps showing after mouseover in IE8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, mouseenter, mouseleave

I have a image which has an mouseover jquery function:

```
$(document).ready(function ()) {
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).children('.item_450_description').stop().fadeTo(500, 1);
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).children('.item_450_description').stop().fadeTo(500, 0);
    }
});
```

When you enter the image with your mouse cursor, a description shows. The description contains a image and a text:

```
<div class="item_450_image">
    <a class="item_popup" href="popup.php?id=1?>"><img src="pic.jpg" class="img_450" /></a>
    <div class="item_450_description">
        <p class="title">Title</p>
        <p class="poster">by poster</p>
        <div class="item_poster">
            <img src="user.jpg" class="img_poster" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When you leave the image with the cursor, the description dissapears. This is working fine in IE9, Chrome, Safari and Firefox. But when I try it in IE8, I have problem.

When I enter the image with the cursor, the description shows (including the image and text). But when I leave the image with my cursor, the description dissapears and also the text. But the image in the description keeps standing and doesn't dissapear.

How can I solve this problem?

(additional css)

```
.item_450_image {
    text - align: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 450px;
    border - top: 1px solid#cdcdcd; - webkit - border - radius: 5px; - moz - border - radius: 5px;
    border - radius: 5px;
    margin - left: 5px;
    padding: 4px 4px 2px 4px;
    background - color: #efefef;
    box - shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); - moz - box - shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); - webkit - box - shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.img_450 {
    width: 450px;
}

.item_450_description {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 4px;
    width: 450px;
    display: none;
    background: url('../img/items/bg_description.png');
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}
```

Comment: try `.stop(true,true).` instead of `.stop().`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add z-index:-1; (or minus something) property to image when mouse leaves, change it with 0 (or some big number) when mouse enters again.

Comment: it has something to do with the <div> around the img. If you leave this out, the img dissapears.